# rowSpan and colSpan of cell are always 1, by Google Document AI processor

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, ocr, cloud-document-ai

```
import json
ifp = open('log.json')
response = json.load(ifp)

for bodyRow in response['document']['pages'][0]['tables'][1]['bodyRows']:
    for cell in bodyRow['cells']:
        print(f'rowSpan is {cell["rowSpan"]}]')
```

[`log.json`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18jIJstuCLXTSbsl2tg5iFCBipfhl54gr/view?usp=sharing) is the ocr and parsed result of table.

I write this Python script to parse this table with Processors "Form parser" by Google documentai_v1beta3, want to find out the `rowSpan` of all cells.

There are some cells that span 2 or 3 rows, but I always get the result 1. Is that a bug of documentai_v1beta3?

Table screenshot:

[image: table screenshot]

Comment: Include a sample of the JSON data in your question.

Comment: added a link to the JSON

Comment: TBH, I am not sure what you are trying to achieve exactly. The [Form Parser](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/form-parser#documentai_batch_process_document-nodejs) is used to send a processing request for a form document (PDF, TIFF, GIF).
Is your document PDF, TIFF or GIF? Also, most of field you mention are not  present in your Json.

Comment: It's PDF. The JSON is result output file of documentai_v1beta3. You can see some row spans in "table screenshot".

Comment: Yes, I agree. What I don't understand is how will you catch anything in your `log.json` with the code you shared if the 'document' and 'pages' keys exists but not the rest of them ('tables', 'bodyRows', 'cells', 'rowSpan'). Did I miss something?

Comment: 'tables's are under the pages keys, ('bodyRows', 'cells', 'rowSpan') are under 'tables', but deeper. It's a big JSON file.

Comment: Hello, I've been struggling with this issue for a while and I would like to shed some light on it, so I filed this [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/177302943). There is missing input information in order to reproduce it so I would encourage you to check it and provide there the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend referring to this documentation about [handling the processing response](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/handle-response#forms_and_tables) for the [Form Parser](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_form-parser) which includes Sample Code and information about the [`Document`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document) object response.